# java msb/lsb in ble communication

Tags: java, android, byte, endianness

I have implemented in android an app that communicate with a device. This device send to me some data and I have to interpretate it.

For example :
when It send me 0x34 I have to to some operation , when 0x35 some other and go on.

When I have to compare a intere byte I don't have problem :
I do something like this :

```
if((byte[0]& 0xff)==0x34) 
  do something
else
 do something else
```

but when I have to interpretate only part  of this byte there is some problem.

For instance :

Take B from this this byte ALPHA : | A(3bit) | B(5bit) | . For do that in correct way I have to do this :

```
B = (alpha&0xFF)>>3;
```

But why ?

I thought that the correct way was :

```
mask = 0x07<<5;
B= alpha && mask
```

Where did I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The BLE [Core Spec](http://bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) uses [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) byte transmission.

> 2.3 Packet Format
>
> All parameters have a little-endian format, i.e. the least significant byte is transferred first.

There are some helper methods in the [BluetoothGattCharacteristic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html) class that can help you read packets, such as [BluetoothGattCharacteristic#getIntValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getIntValue(int,%20int)).